# Stepper Motor Big Easy Driver Undervoltage?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, control

I am trying to get a Phytron Vss42.200.1.2 bipolar 4 winding stepper motor to work, controlled by a BigEasyDriver breakout from an Arduino Mega2560

The Design voltage on the Phytron stepper is 42Vdc. The maximum voltage on allowed on the BigEasyDriver is 30Vdc so this is what I am powering the breakout board with.

I have uploaded a basic sketch, one of the examples(Example 2) from the BigEasyDriver website http://www.schmalzhaus.com/EasyDriver/Examples/EasyDriverExamples.html

The motor is not driving any mechanical load and is still on my desktop. See picture.

When this sketch is running the motor vibrates and turns ever so slightly (maybe 5 to 8 degrees) clockwise and then anitclockwise. I have tested the same code and wiring with a 12V basic stepper (changing the 30Vdc supply to 12V) and it works nicely, rotating 3 to 4 revolutions anti clockwise and then returning the same number of steps clockwise.

Will I be able to use this BigEasyDriver breakout to control the stepper motor or is the voltage too low and not sufficient to move the rotor? Or is there other settings such as step duration that would help this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you swapped the coils. Make sure you connect A coil to A output, and B coil to B output. Check with ohmmeter, which wire is part of the respective winding.
There should be no problem using the driver with lower voltage rating than motor, but you won't ever reach the maximumal speed with lower voltage.

Comment: checked the wiring again, using the multi-meter. No joy. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take into account that the BigEasyDriver's default is 1/16 microstep but the code is written for 1/8 microstep? That could be why your stepper motor is only turning ever so slightly.

Answer (score 1):

The stepper motor has 200 steps per revolution and the BigEasyDriver subdivides that, by default, another 16 micro-steps per full step. In order to make a full revolution the arduino needs to pulse the driver 200 * 16 = 3200 times. Also, check the wiring is connected as 4-Leads
Bipolar mode as desribed in the [datasheet](https://en.xisupport.com/attachments/download/9469/VSS42.pdf).